# Print section number with moderncv

Tags: sectioning, numbering, moderncv

Using `moderncv`, I want to print the section number before the section name. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have done so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Original answer

The `moderncv` class has no provision for numbering sections; it uses a modified `\section` command, so no counter and so on.

You can still modify the `\section` command to produce a number, by adding code such as this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{secnumber}
\newcommand{\numbersec}{\refstepcounter{secnumber}\thesecnumber~}
\patchcmd{\section}{\sectionstyle{#1}}{\sectionstyle{\numbersec #1}}{}{}
```

The `\section` command is patched to produce a number before the section title.

### Complete example

This is taken from the template provided by `moderncv`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,footskip=40pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{secnumber}
\newcommand{\numbersec}{\refstepcounter{secnumber}\thesecnumber~}
\patchcmd{\section}{\sectionstyle{#1}}{\sectionstyle{\numbersec #1}}{}{}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resum\'e title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update

With the most recent version of `moderncv` the above solution won't work.

The code in the top snippet should be substituted with

```
\newcounter{secnumber}
\renewcommand\sectionstyle[1]{{%
  \refstepcounter{secnumber}%
  \sectionfont
  \textcolor{color1}{\thesecnumber~#1}%
}}
```

### Complete example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,footskip=40pt]{geometry}

\newcounter{secnumber}
\renewcommand\sectionstyle[1]{{%
  \refstepcounter{secnumber}%
  \sectionfont
  \textcolor{color1}{\thesecnumber~#1}%
}}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resum\'e title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution isn't working anymore…

Comment: @Clément Updated